# how to make "old" articles behave as "new" in gnus?

Tags: gnus, imap

I am using `gnus` to read mailing lists from an `imap` account. For some reason some (really) new messages are marked by Gnus as ancient, i.e. with <kbd>O</kbd>, they appear in the summary buffer together with the rest of the new messages when I enter a group first time, but they will disappear once I leave the group. Also the navigation commands, e.g. next-article, skip them.

Which settings control the expiration and navigation on such things?

I solved it partially by setting `gnus-summary-goto-unread` to `(quote never)` in `emacs` customization. Now the navigation commands go to any next article in the summary. But the question how to not let them expire is still open.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by "disappear". If they are still around, but not visible, when in the actual mail group you can hit */ o* - which is **gnus-summary-insert-old-articles**, and all the old articles will show up.

If the old articles are being expired, you can change that as follows:
In the gnus **Group** buffer, move to the mail group in question. Then hit *G c* - which is **gnus-group-customize**. This lets you customize the parameters for the particular group - there is a list of parameters you can set.

Look for the entry **Expire Wait**, which you can set to "never".
Next, go back to the top and hit **done**.